# Jquery and PHP , autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, autocomplete

So i just found out about the jquery auto complete and i would like to add it to my web-page. I want to hook it up to my php code so i can search my sql database. However Whenever i try to run my auto complete,it doesnt seem to find the php array im passing ( im just trying to get an array to work for now) . Can someone help?

Jquery Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: "test.php"
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
    $data[] = array(
        'c++','Java','JavScript',"c#" );
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is ` $data[] = array(
        'c++','Java','JavScript',"c#" );` and not ` $data = array(
        'c++','Java','JavScript',"c#" );`

Comment: I actually had the [], just didn’t copy it over correctly. That didn’t work

Comment: And you can have it as $data = array( 'c++','Java','JavScript',"c#" ); BTW

Comment: I think your issue is in your javascript not handling correctly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an updated version of your answer which should resolve the deprecated SQL driver and the injection issue. You need to replace the `SECOND_COLUMNNAME` with your actual column's name. Aside from that I think this should work.

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB','username','password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
if(empty($_REQUEST['term']))
    exit();
//require_once('connect.php'); connection to db is in this file so connection is not needed
$query =  'SELECT name, SECOND_COLUMNNAME FROM locations 
        WHERE name 
        LIKE ?
        ORDER BY id ASC 
        LIMIT 0,10';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(ucfirst($_REQUEST['term']) . '%'));
$data = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = array(
                'label' => $row['name'],
                'value' => $row['SECOND_COLUMNNAME']
                );
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

Links:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Also not sure if there was anything else inside `connect.php`, you might need to bring that back.

Comment: When i added $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(ucfirst($_REQUEST['term']) . '%'));
$data = array();. I wasn’t working

Answer (score 1):

The array pattern used here should be as below.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array("value"=>'C++'),
    array("value"=>'Java'),
    array("value"=>'Javascript'),
    array("value"=>'C#'),
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: It works, but it shows all the elements, instead of the elements that contain the same letters

Comment: Also tried $data = array(
    "value"=>'C++',
    "value"=>'Java',
    "value"=>'Javascript',
    "value"=>'C#'
);  This only returned c# whenever i type in anything

Comment: That will never work. The `value` key will be overwritten every time and you will get only last value.

Comment: I think you need to perform search here.

Comment: Yes sure. Do you use database here?

If you are retrieving data from database table then use similar query according to you.

`$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));`
`$qstring = "SELECT * FROM your_tbl WHERE language LIKE '%".$term."%'";`

Comment: I originally search the sql database, but that wasn’t working so i thought i make is simpler.

Comment: Yes that would be easy for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP >= 5.4:

```
$data = [
    [ 'value' => 'C++' ],
    [ 'value' => 'Java' ],
    [ 'value' => 'Javascript' ],
    [ 'value' => 'C#' ]
];
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Here's a working example of my autocomplete code:

```
function get_data(type, target, min_length )
{
    $(target).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var submit = {
                term: request.term,
                type: type
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/request/get',
                data: { thisRequest: submit},
                dataType: "json",
                method: "post",
                success: function( data ) {
                    response($.map( data.Data, function( item ) {

                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.label
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: min_length
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you post your entire javascript handler?

Comment: Yup, maybe this cant be done by passing array by php

Comment: It can because I use it all the time. Your javascript is wrong. You're echoing a JSON string when autocomplete is looking for a javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        'c++',
        'Java',
        'JavScript',"c#" );
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Nope, will return everything no matter what you type in

Comment: because this code return 4 values - You must write some PHP code to filter results :D

Answer (score -1):

So i want with Pratik Soni advice and did a search. Here is the php code if anyone wants to use it

```
<?php
// Connect to server and select databse.
$dblink = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('DB');
?>

<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST['term']))
exit();
require('connect.php');
  $term = 
  $query = mysql_query('
SELECT * FROM locations 
WHERE name 
LIKE "'.ucfirst($_REQUEST['term']).'%" 
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 0,10', $dblink
  );
  $data = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $data[] = array(
    'label' => $row['name'],
    'value' => $row['name'],
   );   
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
  flush();
```

Comment: This is open to SQL injections and using the deprecated `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Thanks for this , i would love some suggestions to make it better if you have any.

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and get to know it very well.